# C# authentication security best practices

Tags: c#, authentication

I am trying to harden the security of authentication of my C# application.
I have my own server that I authenticate against, and have implemented a service that can create new password hashs from a random salt that is generated on the fly and can verify the password against a saved down password+salt that is hashed. I am saving the hashed pw+salt in an xml file on the server side.

Q1. Is it safer just to store the salt and then have the user enter the password every time he starts a seesion?
Q2. I would like to make it easy for the user (inside of a corporate LAN) and allow the "automatically" be authenticated based on his AD login user name. What is the best way to do this? Can I save a token or a certificate on the client side that times out every week or so?

Cheers,
Lasse

Comment: If your using AD, why not just use Windows authentication? This can prevent users having to login every time. You would plug an AD Membership provider into your config file and make the site trusted.

Comment: Also does anyone know how how to make it SOX compliant?
Do I need to add logging of all failed logons and changes of passwords?

Comment: I don't have control over the AD provider at work and it is to slow to when I want to add users (red tape). Can I setup my own parallel AD provider?

Comment: But you say you want to use AD for login, so how does not using AD Membership Provider make it quicker - they still need to get added first right? All you need is a service account on the domain. Setting up a parallel AD doesn't sound worth the effort. In all my implementations using AD I've never had control over the AD.

Comment: Looks good I can setup my own custom provider without using an SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: BCrypt**

As described in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/do-any-security-experts-recommend-bcrypt-for-password-storage):

> Bcrypt has the best kind of repute that can be achieved for a cryptographic algorithm: it has been around for quite some time, used quite widely, "attracted attention", and yet remains unbroken to date.

I've written up a detailed article about how to implement BCrypt in various frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/bcrypt